# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.SkipPageException

Tags: java, jsp, struts, classnotfoundexception

```
When i run the jsp page i am getting the following error. 
Web sever : Tomcat 6.0 , using Struts 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.SkipPageException 
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680) 
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526) 
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:128) 
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:66) 
at org.apache.jsp.jsp.login.Main_005ffit_jsp._jspService(Main_005ffit_jsp.java:2846) 
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) 
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:386) 
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313) 
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302) 
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1069) 
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:455) 
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:279) 
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482) 
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:507) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) 
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) 
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298) 
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859) 
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588) 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Answer (score 2):

From [the `javax.servlet.jsp.SkipPageException` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/SkipPageException.html):

> #### Since:
>
> JSP 2.0

This particular exception thus suggests that your webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` or, worse, the JRE's `/lib` or `/lib/ext` is polluted with servletcontainer-specific JSP libraries such as `jsp-api.jar` or `j2ee.jar` which originated from a different servletcontainer which supports only an older JSP version.

You should make absolutely sure that you don't have servletcontainer-specific libraries in your webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` folder or elsewhere in the runtime classpath which would only get precedence in classloading over the target servletcontainer's (in your case, Tomcat 6.0's) own libraries.

That they're been placed there is a common starters mistake in an attempt to "fix" compilation errors. It has to be solved differently.

#### See also:

- [How do I import the javax.servlet API in my Eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project/4076706#4076706)